# Съехавшая строка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import lxml
from lxml import html
url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx'
req = requests.get(url)
bs = bs(req.text,'lxml')
vvod = bs.find('tbody').text
USD = vvod[12:20]
USD = re.sub('\n','',USD)
EUR = vvod[22:30]
EUR = re.sub('\n','',EUR)
GBP = vvod[32:40]
GBP = re.sub('\n','',GBP)
print('USD:',USD,'\n','EUR:',EUR,'\n','GBP:',GBP)
```

Вывод:

```
USD: 73.420 
 EUR: 89.322 
 GBP: 99.146
```

Почему все немного съехало и как это исправить?

Answer (score 4):

потому что у функции `print` есть параметр `sep` который равен пробелу, и он вставляется между всеми значениями

```
print('USD: ',USD,'\n','EUR: ',EUR,'\n','GBP: ',GBP, sep ="")
```

либо так чтобы перенос строки и название были одной строкой

```
print('USD:',USD,'\nEUR:',EUR,'\nGBP:',GBP)
```

как сказал `insolor` это можно сделать с помощью трех `print`

```
print("USD:", USD)
print("EUR:", EUR)
print("GBP:", GBP)
```

Comment: Я бы вообще все в одну строку не собирал, не понятно зачем так вообще было делать - по-моему отдельными print-ами было бы нагляднее.